# How can I chain two Netgear routers to make two separate WiFi networks?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, home-networking

I would like to use one ISP account to create two separate WiFi networks. I currently have a Netgear Nighthawk X10 (R9000) router serving as the main router, which is connected to my ISP's modem.

I would like to add a Netgear R6700AX to serve as the secondary router, connected to the main router via ethernet. The R6700AX should broadcast its own WiFi network and allow use of its own ethernet ports.

I've been told that one way to go about this is to set the secondary router as an access point. However, I don't want the devices on either network to be able to see each other (smart devices etc should only be visible on their own WiFi network).

Is there a way to set this up so each device has smooth, uninterrupted internet access?

I was planning on just giving the secondary router a static IP address, and set it to use a completely different address range. For example the main router is using 192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.255, so I could give the secondary router a static IP like 192.168.0.255, and set it to use a network range like 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.255. Is it more complicated than that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can usually follow these steps:

```
Modem -> Router1 -> LAN1(192.168.1.0) -> Router2 -> LAN2(192.168.2.0)
```

- Plug Router2's WAN port into LAN port on Router1
- Give Router2 a static IP (`192.168.1.2`) on router1's LAN network, and a default gateway of Router1 (`192.168.1.1`)

---

The default firewall and NAT settings will block traffic from LAN1 to LAN2, but you may have to vlan Router1's lan port to block traffic in the other direction

Answer (score 0):

With this setup devices in the 2nd (inner) network will be able to "talk" with the whole 1st (outer) network, but not the other way around unless the 2nd network initiates communication.

The most effortless solution is throwing more money at the problem and buying a 3rd router. Disable WiFi on the first one and connect its two LAN ports to other routers' WAN ports. Then set up different IP ranges there than on router 1. You can use the same address range for router 2 and 3. This is basically the same setup you've planned, but doubled. Both routers will be able to reach each other in the outer network, but not the devices inside each other's network.

If you want to put more effort into setting this up, you may be able to get away with just the single R9000. It seems that it supports VLANs. You may try to enable main WiFi and guest WiFi, but put them on separate VLANs. This will isolate devices connected to them within their VLAN. I'm not sure if this model will support such setup though. You may need a more advanced router or a "secondary" router with VLAN support.

A less elegant solution that could work is what you've proposed, but with static routing set up on such a way that only 192.168.0.1 is routable within 192.168.1.0/24. But be warned that I didn't think this through and it may not actually be possible.